# Error parsing data from JSON into database

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to update all products with the prices I get from an API. Right now I'm getting this error when running the script:

```
Array ( [update] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 0 [error] => Array ( [code] => woocommerce_rest_product_invalid_id [message] => Invalid ID. [data] => Array ( [status] => 400 ) ) ) ) )
```

Where am I messing up here? I know it says the ID is invalid, but I'm not really sure of how to iterate over the products without having to address each ID individualy.

```
<?php

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

    $woocommerce = new Client(
        'http://exemple.com',
        'ck_xxxxxxxxxxx', 
        'cs_xxxxxxxxxxx',
        [
            'wp_api' => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v2',
           // 'query_string_auth' => true
        ]
    );

    function parse_json( $file ) {
        $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ), true );

        if ( is_array( $json ) && !empty( $json ) ) :
            return $json;   
        else :
            die( 'An error occurred while parsing ' . $file . ' file.' );

        endif;
    }

    $url = 'https://username:password@apiservice.com/apis/v1.0/xxxxxxxx';

    $json = parse_json($url);

    foreach ($json as $product){

        $data = [
            'update' => [
                 [
                 'id' => (int)$product['id'],
                 'regular_price' => $product['regular_price']
                 ]    
            ]    
        ];
    }

print_r($woocommerce->post('products/batch', $data));
?>
```

This is the data structure of the API I'm trying to get the prices from:

```
[
    {
        "id": "595",
        "type": "simple",
        "parent_product_id": "",
        "name": "Product 1",
        "description": "Descrição",
        "regular_price": "26.78",
        "manage_stock": "1",
        "stock": "5",
        "weight": "0",
        "attribute_name": "",
        "attribute_value": "",
        "has_variations": "",
        "image": "site.com/imagem1.png",
        "sku": "10010"
    },
    {
        "id": "596",
        "type": "simple",
        "parent_product_id": "",
        "name": "Product 2",
        "description": "Descrição",
        "regular_price": "0",
        "manage_stock": "0",
        "stock": "0",
        "weight": "0",
        "attribute_name": "",
        "attribute_value": "",
        "has_variations": "",
        "image": "site.com/imagem2.png",
        "sku": "11010"
        },
(...)
]
```

Comment: Is the API supposed to return an array of product arrays? Or just one product array at a time?

Comment: I included a bigger exceprt of the API to show the structure better. I believe it's an array of product arrays, correct?

Answer (score 0):

its your `$url = 'https://username:password@apiservice.com/apis/v1.0/xxxxxxxx';`

use:

```
$user = 'username'; 
$pass = 'password'   
$url = 'http://apiservice.com/apis/v1.0/xxxxx'
    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$user:$pass")
        )
    ));

    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $json_new = json_decode($data, true);
```